# #define a pointer a->b to another pointer c

Tags: c

Can I do something like

```
#define a->b c
```

I tried that and the compiler complains "ISO C requires whitespace after the macro name"

What I want to accomplish with this is reuse of code. I want to do something like :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define a->b c
#endif
```

Any other ways of doing it?

Comment: No, macro names cannot contain non-name characters. Write it as you would a function (with parameters).

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, and why.

Comment: Can you provide a more elaborate example of this "code reuse" you want to do?

Comment: The fact aside that this is NOT a clean way to do things, shouldn't it be `#define c a->b`?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Quite possibly. But with more parentheses.

Comment: Try to avoid macros like the plague. Use them for simple things. Using them for more complex things only leads to tears when trying to debug your code

Answer (score 6):

The syntax of `#define` is

```
#define <MACRONAME> <MACROVALUE>
```

The **value** should follow the **name** with a `space` in between.
Hence, what you are trying to accomplish is achieved by defining the macro as

```
#define c (a->b)
```

The need for parenthesis surrounding a macro to avoid logical errors is demonstrated **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)**.

---

**NOTE** : However use of macros in this manner is frowned upon. It is difficult to understand the code when essential details are hidden like this. Also there are no benefits with such a coding practice at all, neither in performance nor code-size.

Comment: no benefits?! http://www.ioccc.org/

Comment: FWIW, even **IOCCC** frowns upon the use of `#define`s to obfuscate code. The exact line they use is - *Doing masses of #defines to obscure the source has become 'old'*. Checkout the [official guidelines of IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/2013/guidelines.txt).

Comment: In the real world - where people have to maintain/debug other peoples code - why make their job more tricky than it already is?

Comment: @EdHeal well now that you bring it up, i guess a `#define` is a consultant's dream and a maintainer's nightmare. :P

Comment: Actually I find the nasty nest of `#ifdef`s more of a nightmare.  (And `configure` actively encourages it...)

Comment: In [Going Native 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012), Bjarne Stroustrup recommended that you keep all platform dependent stuff in a single file if possible, and put all the nasty `#ifdef`s there. The rest of the program should be ISO C++. In most cases I agree with that, but obviously splitting it up into a (small) bunch of "platform marshalling" files seems sensible when a lot of platform dependent stuff is required.