# Call by Name/Call by Value

Tags: c++, inline, c-preprocessor, callbyname, call-by-value

I'm trying to understand this block of code here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define mymult(a, b) a*b
inline int mymult1(int a, int b) {return a*b;}

int main() {
cout << "mymult(2+2, 3+3) = " << mymult(2+2, 3+3) << "\n";
cout << "mymult1(2+2, 3+3) = " << mymult1(2+2, 3+3) << "\n";
}
```

mymult = 11, and mymult1 = 24. I know that '#define's essentially work via call by name, rather than call by value. However, I'm having trouble understanding why the value it returns is 11... and not 24. What causes this?

Comment: `#define` is bacisally name substition, so it transforms into `2+2*3+3`

Comment: @predlnik that is the answer!!

Comment: ...which is one of many reasons to prefer inline functions over macros.

Comment: ... and **when** using macros to pass each argument within parantheses.

Comment: ... unless you wish to succeed in obfuscated C-contest....

Comment: @cad, You totally cannot rely on everyone doing that. If you ever write a macro and expect callers to do that when it would have worked by the macro doing that, it's terrible even by macro standards.

Comment: The best way is to avoid the macros altogether, unless really forced not to. Even with parenthesis etc you can still get into trouble. Example from Scott Meyers' book *Effective C++*, item 3: `#define CALL_WITH_MAX(a, b) f((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))` Now do `CALL_WITH_MAX(++a, b)`, and you may end up incrementing `a` twice, in something that looks like perfectly reasonable code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:**
In the case of:

```
#define mymult(a, b) a*b
```

`a` and `b` are treated like place holder strings and when you call `mymult`, the parameters `a` and `b` are just copied as they were written. In other words:

```
mymult(2+2, 3+3) = 2+2*3+3
```

where `a = 2+2, b = 3+3`.

Therefore you may call `mymult` as follows:

```
mymult( (2+2), (3+3) )
```

where `a = (2+2), b = (3+3)`.

This will be interpreted as:

```
mymult( (2+2), (3+3) ) = (2+2)*(3+3)
```

and return the value  of `24` as expected.

**Option 2:**
If we are allowed to modify the `#define` statement then an alternative way of doing this is defining it with the parentheses as follows:

```
#define mymult(a, b) (a)*(b)
```

This will give the same expected result since `a` and `b` will be put directly into the parentheses as they are. In other words:

```
mymult(2+2, 3+3) = (2+2)*(3+3) = 24

where a = 2+2, b = 3+3.
```

**Option 3:**
Stick with the inline function as defined in OP:

```
inline int mymult(int a, int b) {return a*b;}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Or `#define mymult(a, b) (a)*(b)`

Comment: A better fix is to change how `mymult` is defined. `#define mymult(a, b) (a)*(b)`.

Comment: @LogicStuff and @R Sahu : If you are allowed to modify the macro, then yes your suggestion makes more sense. Even, ultimately an inline function is preferable over macro in that particular case.