# #define a b+c confusion..I did not get the output that I expected

Tags: c++

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   # define p 5+3
   int main() {
    //code

    int i=p*p;
   cout<<i;

    return 0;
     }
```

expected output:64
actual output:23
howwW??
I dont understand

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please specify which output you are getting instead of the expected one.

Comment: Very good sample why you shouldn't use macros, especially when not using parentheses as necessary.

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p` will be replaced by `5+3`. So the line `int i=p*p;` is `int i=5+3*5+3;`. `*` has an higher rank than `+`, so the result is `23`.

You need to paranthese your define:

```
#define p (5+3)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 int i=p*p;
```

`p*p` is replaced as `5+3*5+3` ,thus  gives `23 (5+15+3=23)`.As you know `*` will be evaluated before `+` .

Define macro as follows -

```
#define p (5+3)
```