# Comparator as function parameter

Tags: c, c89

Is there any possibility in C89 to pass an operator as function parameter? I mean pass for expample `<`, `==`, `>=` etc. Something like custom comparator in Java, but passed only with particular symbol. Maybe there is solution with special kind of preprocessor macro (I try to use '#' taken from processor macros)?

I know about pointers to functions, but I want something a little bit different.

---

Example:

```
void fun(int a, int b, comperator)
{
    if(a comperator b)
        ........
}
```

Comment: If function pointers are not a solution, you're out of luck; there isn't a way to pass a comparison operator to a function.  You can use comparison operators as an argument to a function-like macro, but that's a macro, not a function.  You could encode the comparators in an enum: `enum Compare { EQ, NE, LT, LE, GT, GE };` and pass that as an argument to a function.

Comment: @anatolyg I want something like this: <blink>    void fun(int a, int b, comperator){ if(a comperator b) ........  }</blink> . But I guess, after all replies that it is not possible in c. Thanks guys for quick response :)

Comment: Why do you want something different than function pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro. But remember - a macro is not a function; it has different (ugly) syntax, some specific problems, some advantages, etc.

Suppose you have a function:

```
int fun(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < y)
        return 1;
    else if (x < 2 * y)
        return 2;
    else if (x < 2 * y)
        return 3;
    else
        return 4;
}
```

To use a different comparator, first convert it to a macro:

```
#define FUN(x, y) \
x < y ? 1 : \
x < 2 * y ? 2 : \
x < 3 * y ? 3 : \
4
```

This conversion is very ugly (it will usually by more ugly than in my example), and not always possible, but now you can add a comparator:

```
#define FUN(x, y, c) \
x c y ? 1 : \
x c 2 * y ? 2 : \
x c 3 * y ? 3 : \
4
```

Usage:

```
printf("%d\n", FUN(3, 5, <));
```

(Note: in macros, you should add parentheses around variables, explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/509868); I omitted them for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

No You cant , just pass it like a string and make a test in the function

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use enums that represent the comparators but with some manipulation you could write a macro wrapper to fun() that calls funLT(), funGT... or enumerates the comparators to LT,GT,.. for use in a switch case.

If `fun(...)` is rather large you probably want to use enums and a switch case inside the function at the appropriate location.

```
enum{LT,GT,EQ,NE,LE,GE};

#define fun(a,b,OP) fun_(a,b, 
   (0 OP 1) \
      ? (1 OP 0) \
         ? NE \
         : (0 OP 0) \
            ? LE \
            : LT \
      : (0 OP 0) \
         ? (1 OP 0) \
            ? GE \
            : EQ \
         : GT \
    )

fun(int a, int b, int op){
//code
  switch(op){
  case GE: //etc...
  }
//more code
}
```

If the function is small you may instead prefer to have separate functions for each operator

```
#define fun(a,b,OP) \ 
   (0 OP 1) \
      ? (1 OP 0) \
         ? funNE((a),(b)) \
         : (0 OP 0) \
            ? funLE((a),(b)) \
            : funLT((a),(b)) \
      : (0 OP 0) \
         ? (1 OP 0) \
            ? funGE((a),(b)) \
            : funEQ((a),(b)) \
         : funGT((a),(b))
```