# Macro usage in C?

Tags: c, macros

I am newbie to C and trying to understand the MACRO expansion logic in C.
I wonder why the first approach is not working but second works as expected.

First approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define square(x) x*x
int main()
{
    int x = 36/square(6); // Expended as 36/6*6
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
// Output: 36
```

Second approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define square(x) x*x
int main()
{
    int x = square(6)/36; // Expended as 6*6/36
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
// Output: 1
```

Could someone explain me the difference ?

Comment: This is bad `#define square(x) x*x` because `square(2 + 1)` would expand `2 + 1 * 2 + 1` which sums `5`.

Comment: As you can read in every C book or tutorial, macros are **text expansion**. Just see them as fancy copy-paste before actual compilation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

```
square(6)/36
```

expands to

```
6*6/36
```

which is equivalent to

```
(6*6)/36
```

and obviously equals `1`.

Even though this is apparently for understanding macros and you may be aware of that, one suggestion:
*macros involving operators should be surrounded by parantheses!*

Comment: Better still - Try to avoid them

Comment: Yeah I know that...but why is the first approach not working ?
i mean 36/6*6

Comment: @kris_lazybum `36 / 6 = 6` and `6 * 6 = 36`. Evaluation order is left to right.

Comment: @EdHeal In C, they might be needed sometimes for true constants and, in my personal opinion, they may be used in C. Not so in C++; IMO, they should have been banished a long time ago.

Comment: @cad - That is why I said that they should be avoided. Using them as constants is fine. Trouble with macros is that they make the code difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

**First expansion**

```
36/6*6
```

Using the rules of precedence and left to right http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence works it out as

```
36/6 * 6 -> (36 / 6) * 6 -> 6 * 6  -> 36
```

**Second expansion**

```
6*6/36 -> (6 * 6)/36 -> 36 / 36 -> 1
```

Using the precedence/left to right rules above.

Sorry for the link - Did not want the cutter. Multiplication has higher precedence than division

Answer (score 0):

Your macro should be defined as

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

It is necessary to enclose the x's in parenthesis to prevent any surprises about operator precedence.  The outer parenthesis are for the same reason.

Please note that this macro even as corrected above will not work if the parameter is a self-modifying expression.  So you may want to consider putting it in all-uppercase or something to alert the user of the macro that it will not behave equivalently to a function call.

The reason your expansion of 36/square(6) does not work as you expect is because of its expansion.

```
36/square(6)
36/6*6
6*6  <-- 36/6 evaluated
36   <-- 6*6 evaluated
```

The corrected macro would be expanded thus

```
36/((6)*(6))
36/(36)
1
```

Which is the answer you would expect.  Also note that 5+1 would also work as an argument because of the inner parenthesis but y++ would not behave as you would expect if reading the macro as a function, hence the reason I recommend naming it SQUARE to alert the user that this is a macro not a function.

Macros only behave as functions if each of their parameters appears exactly once and the syntax is otherwise like an expression (i.e. no {}'s).  Also the user cannot pass a pointer to a macro as they can to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good illustration of the kind of problem that arise with macros:

`36/square(6)` expands to `36/6*6`, which is parsed according to the C grammar as

```
(36 / 6) * 6
```

evaluating to `36`.

If you had defined the macro as

```
#define square(x)  ((x)*(x))
```

Both expressions would be equivalent and evaluate to `1`.

Yet there is still a problem with this macro:

`square(i++)` expands as `((i++) * (i++))`.

Evaluating `i++` twice in the same expression is undefined behavior.