# C calculator by using stack. I want this calculator calculates real number

Tags: c, stack, calculator

My calculator (see code blow) only calculates integer values. However I want to operate with real numbers (ex 12.24+11.06= )

Can you please help me modify my calculator code below? I'm not programming very well and I just started learning, so your help is much appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 50
#define SUM(X,Y) (X)+(Y)
#define MULTI(X,Y) (X)*(Y)
#define DIV(X,Y) (X)/(Y)

typedef struct _Stack
{
char Operator[MAX];
int Operand[MAX];
int Opt_top;
int Opd_top;
}Stack;
Stack stack;

void init()
{
stack.Opd_top = stack.Opt_top = 0;
}

void optPush(char opt)
{
stack.Operator[stack.Opt_top++] = opt;
}
void opdPush(int opd)
{
stack.Operand[stack.Opd_top++] = opd;
}

char optPop()
{
return stack.Operator[--stack.Opt_top];
}
int opdPop()
{
return stack.Operand[--stack.Opd_top];
}
void resetExpression(char Exp[], int len)
{
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    Exp[i] = '\0';
}
int optCheck(char opt1, char opt2)
{
if (opt1 == '*' || opt1 == '/')
{
    if (opt2 == '+' || opt2 == '-')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
else
    return 0;
  }

  int calFunc(int opd1, int opd2, char opt)
  {
int result;
switch (opt)
{
case '+':
    result = SUM(opd1, opd2);
    break;
case'*':
    result = MULTI(opd1, opd2);
    break;
case'/':
    result = DIV(opd1, opd2);
    break;

}
return result;
   }

 void calEngine(char Exp[], int len) {
char tmpExp[MAX] = { 0, };
char ch, opt;
int tmpCnt = 0, opd1, opd2, res, flag = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ch = Exp[i];
    if (ch == ' ')
        continue;
    else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        tmpExp[tmpCnt++] = ch;

        if (Exp[i + 1] == '(' || Exp[i + 1] == ')' || Exp[i + 1] == '+' || Exp[i + 1] == '-' || Exp[i + 1] == '*' || Exp[i + 1] == '/' || Exp[i + 1] == '=')
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                flag = 0;
                opdPush(-atoi(tmpExp));
            }
            else
                opdPush(atoi(tmpExp));
            resetExpression(tmpExp, tmpCnt);
            tmpCnt = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {


            if (ch == '-') {
                flag = 1;
                ch = '+';
            }
            if (stack.Opt_top == 0)
                optPush(ch);
            else
            {
                opt = optPop();
                if (optCheck(opt, ch))
                {
                    opd2 = opdPop();
                    opd1 = opdPop();
                    res = calFunc(opd1, opd2, opt);
                    opdPush(res);
                    optPush(ch);
                }
                else {
                    optPush(opt);
                    optPush(ch);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (ch == '(')
            optPush(ch);
        else if (ch == ')') {
            while (opt != '(') {
                opt = optPop();
                if (opt != '(') {
                    opd2 = opdPop();
                    opd1 = opdPop();
                    res = calFunc(opd1, opd2, opt);
                    opdPush(res);

                }
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '=')
            break;
}
while (stack.Opt_top != 0)
{
    opd2 = opdPop();
    opd1 = opdPop();
    printf("opd1:%d  opd2:%d\n", opd1, opd2);
    opt = optPop();
    printf("opt: %c\n", opt);
    res = calFunc(opd1, opd2, opt);
    printf("result:%d\n", res);
    opdPush(res);
}

  }

int main(void)
{
int j = 1;

while (j <= 100)
{
    printf("%d 번째 계산\n",j);
    char Expression[MAX] = { 0, };
    printf("식 입력: ");
    gets(Expression);
    calEngine(Expression, strlen(Expression));
    printf("%d 번째 계산결과=%d\n\n", j,opdPop());

    j++;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Indent your code properly. 2. Put parentheses around your macro: `#define SUM(X,Y) ((X)+(Y))`, but why using macro instead of functions?

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just have to change the data type of the operands. Make it either `float` or `double` or any similar data type that can handle floating point precision.

You can get an idea of it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type).

Comment: Make it `double`.

Comment: avoid `float` unless you really want it and know what you're going to do