# Preprocessor behind the scenes, how does it interpret the following lines of code C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

So i'm using a preprocessing macro for this basic square function :

```
#define SQUARE(a) a*a
```

it is then passed to these functions, to perform these tasks respectively:

[image]

```
double f(double x) {
    return SQUARE(x);
}
double g(double x) {
    return SQUARE(1-x);
}
double h(double x) {
    return 1/SQUARE(x);
}
```

with such functions, for g(x) and h(x) i'm getting results such as:

```
 g(2) = -3, h(2) = 1
 g(3) = -5, h(3) = 1
 g(4) = -7, h(4) = 1
 etc...
```

I have changed the functions to get their expected results, but I'm curious as to what is happening in the above functions to give me such strange results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQUARE(1-x)` will be expanded to `1-x*1-x` which is not correct at all.

It would be much better to use a function instead of a macro. A function only evaluates the parameter once.

```
double square(double a)
{ return a * a; }
```

Comment: The point of my question was not a code evaluation, it was asking what is happening behind the scenes which gives me results. This code, which I know full well is incorrect, is not in use in my final program, I just want to know why its wrong

Comment: @NoName Literally the first sentence of this answer explains what’s happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the link about the parenthesis , but I don't see why this post deserved to get voted down, I was simply given this formula and asked to give a fix, but i solved it by changing the macros to this `#define f(x) x*x
#define g(x) f((1-x))
#define h(x) 1/(f(x))`
, the original was given without parenthesis, and I was unaware, that that was the cause of the issue

Comment: @NoName The parentheses are *one of the problems*, but there are more (and your “fixed” code doesn’t even fix the parenthesis problem). The real solution here is not to use macros. Out of interest, why are you using a macro instead of a function at all? What do you think this accomplishes? In fact, a macro serves *no* purpose here and is simply wrong. Use a function.

Comment: I just explained that above, I was given a macro, and tasked to fix it (it was a question for Uni assignment) in context of these functions, which I did, but wasn't sure why it wasn't working in the first place, but like Bo said, it was due to parenthesis and false expansion, don't worry, I don't want to be using macros and more than you want me to

Comment: @Bo - you mention that you solved this by fixing g and h. The correct place would be to fix f itself, rather than everyone that calls it. A first pass would be `#define f(x) (x)*(x)`. But - that still suffers other problems, such as double evaluation. For example `f(getNextNum())` would expand to `(getNextNum())*(getNextNum())` which would not do the expected thing (get the next number and square it), but would actually get the next two nums and multiply them...

Comment: ... To solve that you now need do something like `#define sq(x) [](double y){return y*y;}(x)`, but now all you have is a function wrapped up inside a macro. Final answer: This type of macro _just can't_ be "fixed"