# Calculating with a float in macros in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My colleague and I are studying for a test, where we have to analyze C Code. Looking through the tests from the previous years, we saw the following code, which we don't really understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SUM(a,b) a + b
#define HALF(a)  a / 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int big = 6;
  float small = 3.0;

  printf("The average is %d\n", HALF(SUM(big, small)));
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints 0, which we don't understand at all... Can you explain this to us?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: it has to do with format specifier.

Comment: and adding ()'s to macros variables (eg `#define HALF(a)   (a)/2`)

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714). Even if you used to correct format specifier, you'll get surprise results if you don't put parentheses. Just try and see

Comment: Compile with `-E` (gcc or clang) to see the preprocessor output.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` to see the `%d` warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler's warnings (`format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’`)  give more-than-enough information. You need to correct your `format-specifier`, which should be `%lf`, instead of `%d`, since you are trying to print a `double` value.

```
  printf("The average is %lf\n", HALF(SUM(big, small)));
```

`printf` will treat the memory you point as however you tell it to. Here, it is treats the memory that represents the float as an int. Because the two are stored differently, you should get what is essentially a random number. It needs not be `0` always.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: just `%f` is enough

Answer (score 0):

To get correct output

1. Add parentheses in macro
2. Use correct format specifier (`%f`)

Corrected Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUM(a, b) (a + b)
#define HALF(a)  a / 2

int main() {
    int big = 6;
    float small = 3.0;
    printf("The average is %f\n", HALF(SUM(big, small)));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
The average is 4.500000
```

If you don't add parentheses, output will be `7.500000` due to operator precedence.

In case you need integer output, cast to `int` before printing.

```
printf("The average is %d\n", (int)HALF(SUM(big, small)));
```

Output

```
The average is 4
```