# #define ADD(x) (x)+(x) returns wrong result

Tags: c++

I have this function and it adds a number to itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define ADD(x)  (x)+(x)
int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = ADD(++x);

    cout << y << endl;
}
```

When I run this program, it returns 8 but I was expect 6.

I thought x = 3 and it was sending 3 to the ADD function but it seems like it doesn't. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What does it return if you just call ADD(2)?

Comment: It is the old way to create inline function. Try to not do this nowadays.

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Comment: In addition to the problem that this code illustrates, consider what happens with an expression like `2 * ADD(3)`. The result is not 12. The macro needs additional parentheses around the entire expression: `((x)+(x))`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour, because you are calling the preincrement operator twice: `int y = (++x)+(++x);`. Didn't you get a compiler warning for that?

The problem is that `ADD` **is not a function**. It's a macro; it performs textual replacement. Don't use macros for such things in C++.

If you turn the macro into a function, everything will work fine, because then `++x` only appears once:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T add(T x)
{
    return x + x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = add(++x);

    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What `cout <<  add(++x) << endl;` will result? Instead of storing the return in `y`.

Comment: @Raindrop7: Why are you asking? Didn't it print the result of `add` when you tried it?

Comment: Thank you, i understand it now :)

Comment: Not sure it's necessary to bring *templates* in for this level of question, but +1 for the *very* good advice on avoiding macros :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's **undefined behavior**.

When your compiler preprocesses the macro here:

```
int y = ADD(++x);
```

it becomes

```
int y = (++x)+(++x);
```

There is no specified order in which arguments are evaluated.

For more information, see [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](/q/949433)

Comment: coprocessor stage?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for suggest me. I did correction.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not real C++ functions. It's just text replacing.

Your code:

```
int y = ADD(++x);
```

is replaced with:

```
int y = (++x)+(++x);
```

---

You can use a template function instead of the macro.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline auto add(T1 x, T2 y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Worth to mention that `auto` return types were introduced in C++14 and will not work in C++11 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ADD(x)` is actually a macro (as opposed to a real function), `ADD(++x)` evaluates to `(++x) + (++x)` which isn't nice at all because this modifies the same variable, `x`, twice in one statement. The result of such modifications are undefined.

In your compiler's specific case, it incremented the value of `x` from 2 to 3 and then incremented it from 3 to 4. While reading the value of `x` in order to perform `(x+x)`, it chose to read the latest value, which is 4.

I'd suggest that you read up about the differences between macros and functions.