# #define func(x, y) x + y/x

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define func(x, y) x + y/x
int main() {
    int i = -1, j = 2, x;
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("j = %d\n", j);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    x = func(i + j, 3);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

In the C code above, the output is 0 while I expect 4. i.e.

```
i + j = -1 + 2 = 1   
func(i+j, 3) = func (1,3) = 1 + 3/1 = 1 + 3 = 4.
```

Where am I wrong?   Where will I get to learn more about
C-pre-processor macro behavior?

The output of the above code is as below:

[image: Output Console]

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html You have couple of these.

Comment: Use parentheses around your macro expression.

Comment: Do the macro expansion by hand...

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714), and using `x` before initializing is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/995714)

Comment: Run `cpp` on your source file and look at the resulting code. It will be obviouss.

Comment: Tip: for future posts, include text as text, rather than pictures of text.

Comment: Use a function, not a macro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
#define func(x, y) x + y/x
```

To

```
#define func(x, y) ((x) + (y)/(x))
```

Reason :

```
func(x, y) x + y/x  
x = i + j
y = 3
func(x, y) = func(i + j, 3)
=  x + y/x
=  i + j + 3/i + j
= -1 + 2 + 3/(-1) + 2
=  1 - 3 + 2
=  0
```

Comment: Or better still: `#define func(x, y) ((x) + (y)/(x))`

Comment: now call `func(1, 2+3)` or `func(1, 2+3)*4` and see

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you guys.