# what is the difference of these two macro max?

Tags: c, macros

writing [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/description/)
I use the macro like this:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b))?(a):(b)
```

it is wrong,when i change the macro like this,it's right

```
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b))?(a):(b))
```

can't figure out why does this different.Here is the code,you can check it out.

```
#define UNBALANCED 99

#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b))?(a):(b))
int getHeight(struct TreeNode * root)
{
    if(NULL == root)
        return -1;
    int l = getHeight(root->left);
    int r = getHeight(root->right);
    if(UNBALANCED == l || UNBALANCED == r || abs(l-r) > 1)
        return UNBALANCED;

    return 1 + max(l,r);

}
bool isBalanced(struct TreeNode* root) 
{
    if(NULL == root)
        return true;

    return getHeight(root) != UNBALANCED;



}
```

that is different with [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Comment: What's the context in which the first one gets you the wrong result?

Comment: The answer depend on the context in which you use the macros. Please add an example of your code where you use them.

Comment: The simple rule is: always surround a function-like macro with an outer set of parens so that operator precedence doesn't interact unexpectedly with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Comment: This situation may be different in a very strict way than the suggested duplicate (which is about the need to use parens around the macro parameters), but the same rationale applies to the macro as a whole.  Just put parens around the whole macro expression.  The only times you should not have them is when you really know why and can explain that reason to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The former fails to isolate the macro replacement from neighboring operands. For example:

```
1 + max(a, b)
```

expands to:

```
1 + ((a) > (b))?(a):(b)
```

and that groups as:

```
(1 + ((a) > (b))) ? (a) : (b)
```

Then (1 + ((a) > (b))) is always nonzero, so `(a)` is always chosen.

To prevent this, a macro that expands to an expression should use parenthesis around its entire expression to prevent its parts from grouping with neighboring operands.

Comment: I modify the question, in that recursive function,you think it's make a difference?

Comment: you comment is an example explain the former was wrong,in my case,I just return 1+max(l,r), can not  think a reason,why it's different. thanks for your answer

Comment: @52coder: The problem is the same with an operand on the left. I have changed the example to show how it applies in your code.

Comment: thanks, i think i got what you say, + is prior than ?:,when cal from the right as you say it's equal to (1 + ((a) > (b))) ? (a) : (b),thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The second version of your macro has extra parentheses which make the expression `((a) > (b))?(a):(b)` evaluated as a whole. More code would be needed to explain exactly why the first one is wrong in your case. Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Arguably both of them are incorrect; what if you wanted to use your macro like:

```
MAX(i++, j++)
```

The resulting ternary-operator expression from your examples cause whichever expression is smaller to be evaluated twice. Yowch! Since you (and most future readers) likely use GCC or clang, here's a better example with some compiler extensions (`__typeof__` and statement expressions) that both of them support.

```
#define MAX(a, b) ({ __typeof__ (a) a__ = (a); \
                     __typeof__ (b) b__ = (b); \
                     (a__ > b__) ? a__ : b__; })
```

Comment: I think it is different,your example here use i++ and j++,but my example above just use a and b instead of a++  b++,why it's different?

Comment: Your first example is wrong because you don't fully parenthesize your expression, so it is subject to order-of-operations effects at its use site. Other comments and answers have made that clear. I just wanted to add that there is an additional problem you may not have considered when writing your macros.

Comment: using gcc ,how can i know what the compiler explain to the macro i write?