# How can I guarantee one #define is larger than another?

Tags: arduino, c-preprocessor

```
#define MY_CONST 20
#define OTHER_CONST 10
```

My code only makes sense if `MY_CONST > OTHER_CONST`. How can I guarantee this with the preprocessor? Is there any command like this?

```
#assert MY_CONST < OTHER_CONST
```

Comment: `#define MY_CONST OTHER_CONST + 10` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker In my case, the code is clearer when these values are defined separately

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any command like this?
>
> #assert MY_CONST < OTHER_CONST

```
#if OTHER_CONST >= MY_CONST
#error "Error, OTHER_CONST >= MY_CONST"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

as @attersson said #if will do it. 
(as a good habbit try to parenthesize your macros to guarantee order of evaluation for more complex expressions. [this answer shows why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c).)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 10
#define B 11
#if (A) > (B)
  #define RES "yes"
#else
  #define RES "no"
#endif

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("is A larger? %s\n", RES);
        return 0;
}
```