# Why f(0) + f(11) == f(0) in C language by conditional define f(0)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define f(x) (x<10) ? 1 : 3

int main(){
    int i = f(1) + f(11);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Why in this case, the program output "1" but not "4".
How exactly do these two different uses of the defined macro work?

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at what the compiler sees when pre-processing is done,
with some `()` added for clarity:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = (1<10) ? 1 : (3 + (11<10) ? 1 : 3);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the `()` where I added them can be read here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

It shows that `?:` has low priority and the `+` is pushing in to influence the result being evaluated for the first `:` part.

Now it should be clear.

The solution is to generously use `()` within macro definitions.
Comments and other answers have already provided that, I repeat for completeness:

```
#define f(x) (((x)<10) ? 1 : 3)
```

I seem to have even more `()` than other proposals.
Mine also protects against funny things like `f(12||12)` or `f(0&&0)` behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define it like

```
#define f(x) ((x<10) ? 1 : 3)
```

Note the additional parenthesis. This is because the `?` operator has lower  precedence than `+` and your macro is replaced literally, it isn't a function call that returns a result.

Comment: I'd add yet another set of parenthesis surrounding just the `x`: `#define f(x) (((x)<10) ? 1 : 3)` ... for something like `f(u & 0x0f)`

Comment: Correct. Since there is already an answer including this I didn't elaborate further.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not the usual way to define functions, and they don’t work quite like functions usually do. They do *textual replacement* (or, actually, token replacement, but for most purposes that’s close enough. So the compiler sees `main` as

```
int main(){
    int i = (1<10) ? 1 : 3 + (11<10) ? 1 : 3;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Based on how the conditional operator works, this is read as `int i = (1<10) ? 1 : (3 + (11<10) ? 1 : 3)`. Since 1 is less than 10, this sets `i` to 1, and ignores the rest.