# The output of this C code is 49 but can someone explain me how?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUBE(x) (x * x * x)

int main() {
    printf("%d", CUBE(4+5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro will turn the code to:

```c
printf("%d", (4+5 * 4+5 * 4+5));
```

which is effectively:

```c
printf("%d", 4 + (5*4) + (5*4) + 5); // 29
```

If you want to cube `9` to get `729`, you should write `CUBE((4+5))`.

Comment: Or stop using function-like macros. In today's world of optimising compilers, just write it as a function, the compiler will inline it if the benefits are enough (and you can even suggest that to the compiler with `inline`).

Comment: Re “ If you want 729, you should write CUBE((4+5))”: No, the macro should be written with parentheses so its user does not have to supply them.

Comment: @Eric, the amount of macro magic to cover *all* cases (such as `CUBE(x++)`, for example) make function-like macros a very bad idea. Better to just ditch them, use macros for simple definitions, and inline-suggested functions for everything else.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That is irrelevant to my comment. Further, C programmers must understand how macros work even if another one is never written in new code. Advising a person to use inline functions instead is okay for a comment or supplemental information in an answer but does not answer the question asked.

Comment: More commonly, this is taken care of in the macro itself: `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))`

Comment: @Eric, your comment presented a *better* way of doing it but still nowhere *near* fool-proof, as per my given example. I'm not advocating not *learning* about function-like macros since, yes, you will be called upon to fix the inevitable problems with them :-). I'm just stating that they probably shouldn't be used, preferring *actual* functions. Then a vast swathe of problems just go away.

Comment: In any case, there's ample precedent on SO for answering "How do I X?" with "X'ing is a very bad idea, you're better off Y'ing instead" :-)

Answer (score 9):

Here is how the macro is expanded during the compilation process:

```
printf("%d", (4+5 * 4+5 * 4+5));
```

Because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, this expression is evaluated as `(4 + (5 * 4) + (5 * 4) + 5)`, producing `49` instead of the expected `729`.

To avoid such operator precedence issues, all macro arguments must be parenthesised in the macro definition as well as the expression itself:

```
#define CUBE(x)  ((x) * (x) * (x))
```

Note however that this expansion of `CUBE` evaluates `x` multiple times, which is a problem if the macro argument has side effects, such as `CUBE(i++)`.

To avoid all these issues, use a function and let the compiler optimize it:

```
int cube(int x) {
    return x * x * x;
}
```

You can add `static inline` in front of this function definition, but modern optimizers will still inline the function without this.

Answer (score 3):

you need to give the input like `CUBE((4+5))` if you want to add the numbers and then send to `CUBE`. Cause th `CUBE(4+5)` is basically expanded to `4+5*4+5*4+5` as it sets the whole `4+5` in the place of `x`. So, `4+5*4+5*4+5` = `4+20+20+5` as multiplication comes first and then adding them will give `49`.

Define the macro like `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))` it actually first proceed the `(4+5)` operation for every `(x)` and then do the `*` operation.

Another way is just use `CUBE((4+5))` while calling the macro, it basically first added the two numbers and `(4+5)` = `9` and then do `CUBE(9)`, like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CUBE(x) (x * x * x)

int main( )
{
    printf("%d", CUBE((4+5)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The C preprocessor will literally substitute all instances of x for 4+5, resulting in the following code:

```
i = 4+5*4+5*4+5;
```

(multiplication  first, then addition)

Answer (score 1):

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft C standard, and the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and of [CPP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

Take inspiration from existing open source projects, e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), or [GNU software](https://www.gnu.org/software/).

With a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use also the `-C -E` options to get the preprocessed form.

You could also be interested by the [statement-expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension of GCC.

Your `CUBE(4+5)` is macro-expanded to `4+5*4+5*4+5` which is computed as `4+(5*4)+(5*4)+5` according to the precedence of [C operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions).

Consider coding a `static inline` function like

```
static inline int cube(int x) { return x*x*x; }
```

or if you need a macro, at least

```
#define CUBE(X) ((X)*(X)*(X))
```

which won't work nicely for `CUBE(i++)` (while with the `inline` function,  `cube(i++)` does what you want it to do: increment `i` once!).

BTW, you could use [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), (or your own generator, or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)) to generate some C code. As a rule of thumb, think with [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s: when you generate C code, emit a lot of useless parenthesis, like e.g. in [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/), [SWIG](https://swig.org/), or in [CAIA](https://github.com/bstarynk/caia-pitrat) or in my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c)

You could also use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code (and maybe [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)).

You may be interested in reading some coding guidelines like [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) or [GNU ones](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html).