# How to explain define MUX(a,b) a*b?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define MUX(a,b) a*b
```

MUX(10-5,10+5) = 10+5*10-5 = 10+50-5 = 55

I think `MUX(10-5,10+5) = (10-5)*(10+5) = 75`, but it's wrong.

Why? Can anyone explain?

Comment: That's why you should yse parens around macro arguments

Comment: Replace `#define MUX(a,b) a*b` with `#define MUX(a,b) ((a)*(b))` and you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: If you study the output of the preprocessor you'll understand why. See the link of the duplicate.

Comment: duplicate: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because macro replacement is entirely textual. If you want parentheses for correct arithmetic, they must be in the replacement text.

Comment: Macro replacement is based on preprocessor tokens; it is not entirely textual.