# C symbolic constant wrong value

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C. I am wondering why the following `CONST2` is being printed as 13 instead of 18:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


#define CONST 2 + 3 + 4
#define CONST2 CONST * 2


int main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n", CONST, CONST2);
  return 0;
}
```

which using gcc compiler prints:

```
/tmp $ gcc a.c 
/tmp $ ./a.out 
9 13
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `CONST2` expands to `2 + 3 + 4 * 2`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence  You probably want `#define CONST (2 + 3 + 4)`.

Comment: because  2+3+4*2 is 13

Comment: Means #defined symbols are replaced exactly with the string of their values, rather than with the actual value?

Comment: @Student: Correct, more or less.

Comment: @Student yes, macros are replaces exactly as they were written.

Comment: To be precise, the string *is* the actual value of the macro, at this point in compilation.

Comment: macros are texts replacement, it happens before compilation so obviously it knows nothing about expressions. duplicate: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)