# How `(1U << 1) | (1U << 5)` is different from `0x22`?

Tags: c, if-statement, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Would someone please explain me how having the same value `VAL1` and `VAL2` behave differently?
For the first `if` statement `VAL1` is equal to zero?
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VAL1 (1U << 1) | (1U << 5)
#define VAL2 0x22

int main()
{
    printf("VAL1: %d\r\n", VAL1);
    printf("VAL2: %d\r\n", VAL2);

    if (VAL1 == 0)
    {
        printf("TRUE 1\r\n");
    }

    if (VAL2 == 0)
    {
        printf("TRUE 2\r\n");
    }

    if (VAL1 == VAL2)
    {
        printf("TRUE 3\r\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
VAL1: 34
VAL2: 34
TRUE 1
TRUE 3
```

Comment: Mind operator precedence. Fully parenthesize macros.

Comment: Indeed, it works. Such a small detail, yet a big difference. But why exactly is it like that?

Comment: `#define VAL1 (1U << 1) | (1U << 5)` ==> `#define VAL1 ((1U << 1) | (1U << 5))` To find out why, write down the expansion.

Comment: There are two cardinal rules for writing correct expression macros:  (1) In the macro body, wrap each argument (if any) in parentheses, and (2) Wrap the entire macro body in parentheses.  Failing to do either of these can result in undesired association in the instantiated macro.  You forgot (2), and as a result, part of your macro grouped more tightly with a comparison operator, resulting in undesired behavior.

Comment: @Tom Karzes while your rules are fine for most  expressions, they can cause syntax errors with string literals. Consider #define PREF( a) "pref" a which could be used to prepend "pref" to a string literal as in PREF( "suf") which expands to "pref" "suf" which the compiler converts to "prefsuf". If you apply either of your rules to PREF you get a syntax error on expansion. Admittedly PREF is a bit nasty, but that's macros!

Comment: @dmuir That's not an expression macro.  An expression macro expands to an *expression*, not a string constant that can be concatenated with other string constants.  My wording was very precise.  Perhaps if you read it again you'll understand it better.  This is well-known C macro style that any experienced C programmer knows.

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `if (VAL1 == 0)`, macro replacement changes the source code to `if ((1U << 1) | (1U << 5) == 0)`.

The expression inside the `if` is evaluated as `(1U << 1) | ((1U << 5) == 0)`, [due to a desire to keep C’s operator precedences consistent with those of the earlier language B](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/chist.html).

Thus we have `if ((1U << 1) | ((1U << 5) == 0))`, in which `(1U << 1)` evaluates to 2 and `((1U << 5) == 0)` evaluates to 0, resulting in `if (2 | 0)`, which becomes `if (2)`, so the statement with the `if` is executed.

It is customary to define a macro replacement that is an expression with parentheses to ensure it is grouped as one item:

```
#define VAL1 ((1U << 1) | (1U << 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are both the same, but when your macro expands in you conditions, it does not behave as you expect due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

In other words, here's what you get when expanded:

```c
(1U << 1) | (1U << 5) == 0
// is equivalent to
(1U << 1) | ((1U << 5) == 0)
```

Comment: Solution: `#define VAL1 ( (1U << 1) | (1U << 5) )`