# C Programming Macros multiplication

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

I found this macro question to be very interesting.

If this following code is defined as a Macro

```
#define MULT(x, y) x * y
```

And the function call is made as `int z = MULT(3 + 2, 4 + 2);`.
The Desired output is 3+2=5 and 4+2=6 And 5*6 to be 30.

But the returned output was 13.
It takes it as 3+2*4+2. Hence according to the precedence of operators it evaluates 2*4 first.

What is the fix here? 
In case of smaller functions like these which one is efficient? Defining the function or using the macros?

Comment: How do you measure efficiency? Coding time, execution time, maintainability...

Comment: The macro is probably more efficient. If the optimiser inlines the function they will probably be equivalent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#define MULT(x, y) ((x)*(y))
```

Comment: Thank you. But the question was more concerned about efficiency.

Comment: @Katti: how is this in any way related to efficiency ?

Comment: Why not just use `x * y` and skip the macro or function, then?

Comment: @PaulR, fewer parentheses, smaller compile time. Bam! (Just kidding)

Comment: Macros are direct substitution and functions are called and the data is sent to them. So there has to be some difference is what I felt.

Comment: @Katti: bad assumption - an inline function is just as efficient as a macro - there is rarely a reason to use a macro for this kind of thing with modern compilers.

Comment: A function would be slower (unless you inline it/the call gets optimized away).

Comment: @Katti, you must believe in the intelligence of compilers nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define MULT(x, y) ((x) * (y))
```

Personally, I think it's more readable (and fewer keystrokes) to *not* use the macro.  This is the kind of thing that someone will start adding to their code in the rush of learning new things and regret later on.

Comment: You are still missing parentheses. Imagine `z/MULT(x, y)`