# do - while constructs within #define

Tags: c, macros, do-while

Inside include/linux/sched.h one of the important task state changing functions is:

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)      \
    do { (tsk)->state = (state_value); } while (0)
#define set_task_state(tsk, state_value)        \
    set_mb((tsk)->state, (state_value))
```

As you can see there is a do while() structure inside #define __set_task_state(...).

Now my question is, is it just like any other C do-while loop code - or does it have special properties as it is defined inside #define macro?

Thanks

Comment: It is just like any other do-while loop.

Comment: Note that it's condition is while(0), so it's not really a loop since its body will only ever execute once. It's used merely to ensure that the code in the body will nest properly within other code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116171/dowhile0-macro-safety (and many other stackoverflow questions about this)

Comment: @ooga Thats interesting I would expect just having (tsk)->state = (state_value); to nest not worse than the do-while() structure above. To me the 'nestability' does not seem too obvious.

Comment: @Anup, I agree. In this case it should not be necessary. But that's what the construct is usually used for. Perhaps there was originally another line of code and the do/while was just left in. BTW, the compiler will not generate any code for it, so there's no loss of efficiency. Also, I'm not sure why simple braces aren't used.

Comment: Only one word: **scope!**

Comment: @ichramm Scope? What do you mean...Can you please explain a little further...

Comment: the other answer explains far better then me but I use them not only to force the usage of semicolon but also because it allows me to create local variables without collision.