# When can the parentheses around arguments in macros be omitted?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, parentheses

Often and often I felt some of the parentheses around arguments in macro definitions were redundant. It’s too inconvenient to parenthesize everything. If I can guarantee the argument needs not be parenthesized, can I omit the parentheses? Or is parenthesizing them all highly recommended?

I came up with this question when I wrote:

```
#define SWAP_REAL(a, b, temp) do{double temp = a; a = b; b= temp;}while(0)
```

I think that if an argument appears as an l-value in the macro, the parentheses can be omitted because that means the argument appears with no other operation.

My reasoning is:

1. The associative priority of assignment symbols is merely higher than comma’s.
2. You cannot confuse the compiler into thinking that your argument is an expression with a comma in it. For example, `SWAP(a, b, b)` will not be interpreted successfully as

   ```
   do{double temp = a, b; a, b = b; b= temp;}while(0)
   ```

   which can pass compilation.

Am I right? Can anyone give me a counter-example?

In the following example,

```
#define ADD(a, b) (a += (b))
```

I think the argument `a` needn’t be parenthesized. And in this specific case, neither needs the argument `b`, right?

@JaredPar:

> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    #define ADD(a, b) (a += (b))
>    int main(){
>       int a = 0, b = 1;
>       ADD(a; b, 2);
>       return 0;
>    }
> ```

This cannot be compiled successfully on my VS2010. `Error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'`

---

**In a nutshell, you don’t need to parenthesize the arguments having appeared as an l-value in the macro, but you are highly recommended to parenthesize them all.**

Rules of Macros:

1. DO NOT make macros with side effects!
2. As for macros with no side effect, just parenthesize all the arguments without second thought!
3. As for macros with side effect, stop being obsessive! Parenthesize them all! TnT

Comment: If you need to use a macro that isn't fully parenthesized, how much time will you spend figuring out whether it's safe in all cases?

Comment: @KeithThompson conversely, how will you know you wrote a macro correctly if you didn't know what needed to be parenthesized?

Comment: Maybe instead consider the reverse question -- what macros that one might plausibly write will in fact be broken by defensive parenthesis?

Comment: I just hate the feeling when I am parenthesizing the variables with the doubt of its necessity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you're demonstrating with MIN...I said that if you omit the parentheses around the arguments, things won't work properly, and your test with error C2106 confirms this.  If you use the fully parenthesized macro arguments, there won't be an issue.  So, AFAICT, you're agreeing with what I said.

Comment: As for your SWAP macro, it depends on what the rules are.  Clearly, you can't swap `x+3` with `y-2`, but you can't assign to r-values.  The arguments to SWAP must therefore be modifiable l-values, and I don't think there's likely to be a case where you could write a call where there'd be a problem.

Comment: @djechlin: You don't need to know what absolutely *needs* to be parenthesized. Just put parentheses around each reference to a macro parameter, and around the entire definition, and you'll be reasonably safe from operator precedence errors. (Unless you're doing something that plays games with the language syntax, but that should be rare.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Eh. I thought "won't be misinterpreted as they could be" meant "will be interpreted correctly as they should be" and I tested it...Seems like I misunderstand you..

Comment: @Moon: Seriously, the solution is to stop hating that feeling.

Comment: Just don't do macros. That's it, problem solved.

Comment: I said 'if you are using the arguments in most arithmetic expressions, then you do need to wrap them in parentheses' and illustrated a macro with fully wrapped arguments, and then said '[b]ut the arguments won't be misinterpreted as they could be if you wrote' and illustrated with a macro without fully wrapped arguments and an invocation that was more or less bound to cause trouble — where the expressions would be misinterpreted — and your example demonstrates that they are indeed misinterpreted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry...Are you sure you mean "**won't** be **mis** interpreted"? I think you were about to say "will be misinterpreted if you don't parenthesize them all"

Comment: I meant what I said, but maybe it isn't simple enough English to be fair on you.  I think it _is_ unambiguous to a native speaker, but it could be written more simply. Maybe: _If you using macro arguments in arithmetic expressions, then you need to wrap them in parentheses prevent misinterpretation. If you write the macro body with parentheses around all arguments, the arguments won't be misinterpreted.  If you don't write the macro body with parentheses around all arguments, expressions in the macro invocation can be misinterpreted._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah...I got it... You mean _the arguments won't be misinterpreted (when fully parenthesized) as they could be (when not fully parenthesized) if you wrote:_ Thanks for your patience:)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unsafe to omit if you use any operator that isn't lowest precedence in your expression. I believe that would be comma.

`a op b` where `op` is some operator like `+`, `*` etc. will always bind wrong if `a` contains an expression of low precedence like `1 || 2`.

Note I'm *not* claiming it's safe in those cases. There are more creative ways to break macros. By the way, don't use macros with side effects in the first place. More generally, don't use macros as functions. (See, e.g., Effective C++).

Comment: Thanks, djechlin. You gave me the hint on why I came across the problem: I encapsulated code with side effects as a macro. If there is no assignment in the macro, just parenthesize all the variables. But there are cases where I want to encapsulate two or more assignments together and I don't think they deserve to be a function (too short are they). So I combined them in a macro. In this situation, should I still combine them as a function, in pure C especially?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one case where it makes a demonstrable difference

```
ADD(x;y, 42)
```

With parens this leads to a compilation error but without it leads to code that compiles.

```
(x;y) += 42; // With parens errors
x;y += 42;   // Without parens compiles
```

This may look like a silly example but it's possible combining macros together can easily lead to strange code expressions like the above.

Why take the chance here?  It's just 2 characters

Comment: Hi, JaredPar. Thanks for your answer but I think your example is wrong. I tried your code and it will dump out errors during compilation. The error message is "error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'". Also, ADD is just a simplest example. In this case "#define SWAP_INT(a, b) do{int temp = a; a = b; b = temp;}while(0)", I think a and b needn't to be parenthesized.

Comment: @Moon I've verified that if x and y are defined tho code executes as my answer stated

Answer (score 2):

There are macros where you're concatenating elements to make a string (perhaps using the `#` operator), or building identifiers out of macro arguments using the `##` operator. In such cases, you don't parenthesize the arguments.

Also, I think that when the macro arguments are themselves passed as function arguments, then you don't absolutely have to parenthesize them:

```
#define CALLOC(s, n) calloc(s, n)
```

You can play fiendish games calling such a macro (`CALLOC({3, 4})`), but you get what you deserve (a compilation error) — I'm not aware of a way of calling that macro that would work if instead of the macro you wrote the same arguments as a direct call to `calloc()`.

However, if you are using the arguments in most arithmetic expressions, then you do need to wrap them in parentheses:

```
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
```

Obviously, if you invoke it with arguments with side effects, then you get what you get. But the arguments won't be misinterpreted as they could be if you wrote:

```
#define MIN(x, y) x < y ? x : y
```

and then invoked it as:

```
MIN(x = 3 * y + 1, y = 2 * x - 2);
```

---

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964369/when-can-the-parentheses-around-arguments-in-macros-be-omitted#comment31493943_20964501) by [Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3127828/moon) suggests a `SWAP_INT` macro.

The following code using that macro compiles cleanly when compiled using default options, but fails to compile with `-DWITH_PARENTHESES` set.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef WITH_PARENTHESES
#define SWAP_INT(a, b) do { int temp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = temp; } while (0)
#else
#define SWAP_INT(a, b) do { int temp = a; a = b; b = temp; } while (0)
#endif

int main(void)
{
    int p = 319;
    int q = 9923;
    int x = 23;
    int y = 300;

    printf("p = %8d, q = %8d, x = %8d, y = %8d\n", p, q, x, y);
    SWAP_INT(p, q);             // OK both ways
    SWAP_INT(x, y);             // OK both ways
    printf("p = %8d, q = %8d, x = %8d, y = %8d\n", p, q, x, y);
    SWAP_INT(x /= y, p *= q);   // Compiles without parentheses; fails with them
    printf("p = %8d, q = %8d, x = %8d, y = %8d\n", p, q, x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
p =      319, q =     9923, x =       23, y =      300
p =     9923, q =      319, x =      300, y =       23
p = 41150681, q =       13, x =        0, y =  3165437
```

That isn't a safe or effective way of swapping integers — the macro without the parentheses is not a good idea.

JFTR: when compiled without `-DWITH_PARENTHESES`, the line for the macro with the expressions is inscrutable:

```
do { int temp = x /= y; x /= y = p *= q; p *= q = temp; } while (0);
```

Normally, a swap macro expects two variable names — or array elements, or structure or union members, or any mix of these.  It does not expect to be given arbitrary expressions.  The parentheses ensure that the assignment to `x /= y` (which is not an lvalue) fails; without the parentheses, the expression is interpreted, but it isn't anything like what was intended (if, indeed, anything could be intended when 'swapping' two expressions like that).

Comment: I tried `CALLOC({3, 4})` on VS2010 and it cannot pass compilation. Could you please give me some further explanation? I thought you mean "`CALLOC({3, 4})` can be successfully invoked but `calloc({3, 4})` cannot". Did I misunderstand you again?...

Comment: It is bogus; it should not compile; you get what you deserve — an error message — for calling a macro/function with invalid arguments.