# Difference between redefinition of array elements in C

Tags: c, redefinition

I am a beginner in C and During Programming I have found this code about bitwise addition

```
#define WORD_FROM_BUF(WRD) ((((unsigned char *)(WRD))[0]<<8)|((unsigned char *)(WRD))[1])
```

I have tried to modify this code to this form

```
 #define WORD_FROM_BUF(WRD) (((unsigned char *)(WRD[0])<<8)|((unsigned char *)(WRD[1]))
```

**EDIT**
My problem is similar to these 2 questions
[C macros and use of arguments in parentheses- by Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

[Can we remove parentheses around arguments in C macros definitions?- by Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752386/can-we-remove-parentheses-around-arguments-in-c-macros-definitions)

Thanks everyone for your explanations

Comment: Two words: operator precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Comment: Ugh.  IMO that's really bad code.  Waaaay too much is crammed into that macro - which is why you're having problems figuring out what's going on.  It's screaming to be replaced by a function that gets inlined during optimization...

Comment: What is your objective in modifying the original code, anyway?  Random rearrangements of symbols in the source should be expected generally to lead to different results (often compilation errors, but sometimes differently-working valid programs).

Comment: Apart from the second example having unbalanced parentheses, the casts in the first example modify `WRD` (before indexing the result) but in the second they modify `WRD[0]` and `WRD[1]` (after indexing the pointer). The actual offset of index `[1]` in bytes depends on the type of the pointer.

Comment: I was only trying to see the result of changing the original code, as it seemed strange to me to put the original declaration between parentheses (WRD). and when I saw the error in the second code I did not understand why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(unsigned char *)(WRD)` takes the pointer(?) `WRD` and converts it into a pointer to bytes. Indexing that byte-pointer with `[0]` gets the first byte from the buffer. When combining that with the next byte, you get a two-byte value.

`(unsigned char *)(WRD[0])` takes the first word(?) from the buffer and turns *that* word into a pointer. Totally different, and very likely totally wrong as shifting the pointer `<< 8` make little sense.

Then `WRD[1]` picks up the second word from the buffer, not the second byte.

Comment: your answer explains everything. Thanks for your explanation