# (C/C++) how to create a macro that accepts the increment operator

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

to make my question precise i would like to create a macro that accepts as variable ++ and pastes it with another variable. In code:

```
#define MYMACRO(A, OP) /* .... */
```

and then if i write in the source file

```
MYMACRO(this->var, ++)
```

the preprocessor should paste in the code

```
this->var++;
```

When i am trying to define the macro as A##OP , it provides the following error:

> pasting "++" and "var" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Is it possible to do what i am trying?

thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: Your macro would not make sense.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  In C++ I would suggest making a template function.

Comment: `##` is used for pasting two tokens into a single token, e.g. `MYMACRO(foo, bar)` results in the variable `foobar`. But `this->var++` is multiple tokens, so you can't paste them together like that. It doesn't work at the text level, so it doesn't just put things next to each other and reparse it.

Comment: There is no place for macros such as this in c++. You're 15 years behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine the tokens like this:

```
#define MYMACRO(a, incrdecr) (a)incrdecr
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `##` token pasting operator, because you're not trying to combine the parameters into a single token. Just use:

```
#define MYMACRO(a, op) (a)op;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *would have preferred to answer that as* `#define MYMACRO(a, op) ((a)op)` instead (but what the OP wants is kind of silly, including the semicolon in the macro).

Comment: Technically you're not doing what the OP asked for. The OP's example does *not* introduce parentheses.

Comment: @EOF True, but parentheses are needed in case `a` has subexpressions that have lower precedence than the operator.

Comment: @Barmar Unless the OP *wants* `MYMACRO(*ptr, ++)` to modify the pointer rather than the pointed-to object. In the absence of anything the OP has said about this, you should *probably* not introduce bugs for them.

Comment: If the parentheses are unwanted, a space would work too: `#define MYMACRO(a, op) a op`

Comment: @EOF Without specific information to the contrary, I assume that people want function-like macros to be parsed similar to functions, where the comma has the lowest precedence. Failing to add parentheses is usually the *cause* of unexpected behavior.

Comment: @EOF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862207/bad-parentheses-in-macro-definition?s=1|1.8332

Comment: thanks @Barmar. Thats what i was looking for. Although i had already somehow found a way around it to do what i needed

Comment: I wonder why you accepted the other answer instead of mine. The code is the same, but I added more explanation of the problem with your code.