# Why putting a macros argument in parentheses leads to an error?

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor-directive

I have one very interesting question about preprocessor directives in c++.

Consider the following macros and his usage:

```
    #define FUNCTION(a, b) void (a)(int &current, int candidate)\
    {\
        if ((current b candidate) == false){\      // Marked Line    
            current = candidate;\
        }\
    }

    FUNCTION(minimum, <)
    FUNCTION(maximum, >)
```

My question is why changing the "Marked Line" with the following line of code won't even compile:

```
     ... if ((current (b) candidate) == false) ...
```

Comment: Because `(<)` is not valid. Try it without the macro.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with macros.  [See for yourself](https://ideone.com/zWCajh).

Comment: Instead of showing code that works, show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just take a functor, like std::greater, or std::less?

Comment: You better do that with a template

Comment: This question is not interesting at all. Using preprocessor directives this way is abominable and disgusting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because '<' is a binary operator and it cannot be evaluated without an operand on either side. You can verify this without macros simply by attempting to compile the following code:

```
bool LessThan( int a, int b )
{
    return( a (<) b );
}
```

At the very least you should see "expected an expression" or a similar error.

Comment: Ok. I understood it but what is the idea of putting the macros argument in parentheses so?

Comment: See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Comment: Normally people advise you to put arguments in parentheses because the macro preprocessor does very simple, literal text substitutions that can lead to incorrect code. The advice breaks down when a macro argument is an operator rather than an expression.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I appreciate your help!