# Cannot take address of bit-field ‘ihl’ or any bit field

Tags: c

I have this helper function that I like to define so it looks like for one specific function

```
int change_int_val(unsigned int * from,unsigned int *to)
{
    *to=*from;
    return 0;
}
```

So actually it assign the `from` to `to`  now the problem is I want to pass all  fields that I have in my struct so assume I  have `struct iphdr` from networking and I want to assign value 5 to ihl which is 4 bit size defined as `unsigned int ihl:4;` now if I call the above function like this

```
 change_int_val((unsigned int *)5,(unsigned int *)(&ip->ihl));
```

I get error that

```
tcp_work.c:45:59: error: cannot take address of bit-field ‘ihl’
   45 |         change_int_val((unsigned int *)5,(unsigned int *)(&ip->ihl));
```

So can I make this helper function like the one above and escape this limitation that pointer size 1 byte issue with fields that are less than 1 byte in my case as I like to pass the address of `iphdr->ihl` to my helper function `change_int_val`

Comment: like to pass the address of ->ihl to the helper function

Comment: `(unsigned int *)5` only makes sense on smaller embedded systems where you need a pointer to the actual memory at address `5`. Not anywhere else.

Comment: Also, the smallest addressable unit on any CPU the last 40-50 years or so is the *byte*. You can't have pointers to individual bits.

Comment: Oh and please don't forget how to create a *[mre]* to show us. While we can deduce some information, having the bitfield structure itself doesn't hurt.

Comment: Lastly, what is wrong with plain assignments? Like `ip->ihl = 5` (which is what I assume you want to do)?

Comment: If I understand you want to manipulate `struct iphdr` within the function, why not pass `struct iphdr *` as one of the parameters and then change the value of the bitfield directly within the function?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ok also can u tell why fields that are less than 1 byte are normally don't need  ntohs byte order function or or ntohl kind of conversion but bigger fields sized more than 1 byte needs byte order conversion for example ihl and protocol dont need ntohs conversion

Comment: There is a good question discussing bitfields at [When to use bit-fields in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c) and see the answer to [C/C++ Is bitfield endianess really a problem in actual practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081370/3422102) (discussing `struct iphdr`)

Comment: Regarding `ntohs` and similar, it's for *byte* ordering of *multi-byte* values (like 16- or 32-bit values).