# i don't understand why this program prints these results

Tags: c

this program prints out -8 -4 but i wanna know why and why isn't the compiler showing an error about which function to use? why are the results different.
i don't know much about defining a function like this can someone explain this too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(int x, int y);

#define foo(x, y) x/y + x

int main() {
    int i = -6, j = 3;
    printf("%d ", foo(i + j, 3));
#undef foo
    printf("%d\n", foo(i + j, 3));
}

int foo(int x, int y) {
    return x/y + x;
}
```

Comment: Did you work through it on paper? When you `#define` something that has very high precedence and over-rules any function definitions.

Comment: What do you think the expected results are?

Comment: @tadman oh i didn't know that but aren't these functions the same? if they are, shouldn't they print the same result?

Comment: @lgal S. -4 and -4?

Comment: If you expand the macro by hand you might be surprised: watch out for the lack of parentheses. It is not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Comment: @Angela -42 and -42?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you preprocess the call to the macro `foo`, you get:

```
i + j / 3 + i + j
```

With your values, that's

```
(-6) + 3 / 3 + (-6) + 3
```

Which evaluates to `-8`.

When you undefine the macro `foo`, you get the function `foo` instead, where the line `return x + y / x` is executed.

With `i = -6` and `j = 3`, you get:

```
(-3) / 3 + -3
```

Which is `-4`.

Further reading:

- [Operator Precedence in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
- [#defines are EVIL](https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/defines-are-evil/)

Comment: Sadly in C `#define` is often a *necessary evil*.

Answer (score 3):

These two functions are not equivalent due to operator precedence rules.

Remember a `#define` macro does *inline substitution* and the arguments themselves are replaced as-is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int oper_fn(int x, int y) {
    return x/y + x;
}

#define oper_def(x, y) x / y + x

int main() {
    int i = -6, j = 3;
    printf ("oper_fn=%d ",oper_fn( i + j , 3));
    printf ("oper_def=%d\n",oper_def( i + j , 3));
}
```

What this ends up doing is evaluating:

```
i + j / 3 + i + j
```

Due to order of operations, this evaluates as:

```
i + (j / 3) + i + j
```

That's not what you want, instead you want:

```
(i + j) / 3 + (i + j)
```

Which means you need the macro:

```
#define oper_def(x, y) ((x) / (y) + (x))
```

That's how macros are written normally to avoid ambiguity and inconsistency like this.

Comment: In the proper macro definition, wouldn't it make more sense to wrap the whole expression in a pair of parentheses? `#define oper_def(x, y) ((x) / (y) + (x))` Then an expression like `int z = 3*oper_def(7,1) + 4;` will give you the expected result.

Comment: @ndim That's another important suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#define` is not at all like the function. It evaluates as

```
printf ("%d ",i + j / 3 + i + j);
```

which will naturally generate a different result to the function as the parameters passed the function are evaluated so it sees `x` as -3 and `y` as 3.

Answer (score 0):

when you define

```
 #define foo(x, y) x / y + x
```

and then do

```
 foo( i + j , 3));
```

you get

```
 i + j / 3 + i + j
```

which is

```
 -6 + 3/ 3 + 3 -6 = -6 + 1 + 3 - 6 = -8
```

when you call the function foo the i+j is evaluated first

if you want the correct define behavior then do

```
#define foo(x, y) ((x / y) + x)
```

You have just discovered why `define`d functions are a bad idea

Comment: you should probably put parentheses around the `x`s and `y` as well, since your example will still compile as `((i + j / 3) + i + j)`

Comment: Normally the `x` and `y` should each by individually parenthesized in the macro definition; i.e., `#define foo(x, y) ((x) / (y) + (x))` to handle the case where the macro argument is itself an expression.