# Check if a bit is set using a MACRO

Tags: c, bitmap

I created a MACRO to see if a bit is set or not. Code is printing 0 instead of 1.

```
#define IS_BIT_SET(n,x)   ((n&(1<<x)!=0)?1:0)
int main(){
    printf("%d \n",IS_BIT_SET(8,3));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!=` operator has a higher precedence than `&`.

So your:

```
n & (1 << x) != 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
n & ((1 << x) != 0)
```

Which, for any value of `x` that gives a well-defined result, is equivalent to:

```
n & 1
```

Which isn't what you want.

To fix this. replace your define with:

```
(((n & (1 << x)) != 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

Also, your arguments should probably be wrapped in parentheses if you plan on using this in a more complex situation:

```
((((n) & (1 << (x))) != 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

Instead of using a ternary, you can use the fact that the `!=` yields an `int` of value `0` or `1`:

```
(((n) & (1 << (x))) != 0)
```

Alternatively, you can skip the comparison to `0`, and cast to `bool` and back to `int`:

```
((int) (bool) ((n) & (1 << (x))))
```

Or stick with the ternary, dropping the comparison to `0`:

```
(((n) & (1 << (x))) ? 1 : 0)
```

Which one you choose of these last three is a matter of opinion and preference.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just wanted to understand more why are we adding parentheses around the arguments?

Comment: Please see [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses).

Comment: Parentheses will make a difference in a case like this:  IS_BIT_SET(8,3) returns 1, while IS_BIT_SET(8,2|1) returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison `!=` has higher precedence than `&` so it's done first. Your code therefore is doing `8 & ((1 << 3) != 0)` which is `8 & 1`. You need to add parentheses:

```
#define IS_BIT_SET(n,x)   (((n & (1 << x)) != 0) ? 1 : 0)

int main(){
    printf("%d \n",IS_BIT_SET(8,3));
}
```

Now it will be understood as `(8 & (1 << 3)) != 0` as you want it to be.