# C: Parathesis around a variable without other operands

Tags: c, freertos

I'm studying the source code of FreeRTOS. I found this snippet:
https://github.com/TheKK/myFreeRTOS/blob/master/include/list.h#L268

```c
#define listGET_OWNER_OF_NEXT_ENTRY( pxTCB, pxList )                                        \
{                                                                                           \
    List_t * const pxConstList = ( pxList );                                                \
    /* Increment the index to the next item and return the item, ensuring */                \
    /* we don't return the marker used at the end of the list.  */                          \
    ( pxConstList )->pxIndex = ( pxConstList )->pxIndex->pxNext;                            \
    if( ( void * ) ( pxConstList )->pxIndex == ( void * ) &( ( pxConstList )->xListEnd ) )  \
    {                                                                                       \
        ( pxConstList )->pxIndex = ( pxConstList )->pxIndex->pxNext;                        \
    }                                                                                       \
    ( pxTCB ) = ( pxConstList )->pxIndex->pvOwner;                                          \
}
```

I know that `( pxConstList )->pxIndex` means access the data of pointer variable pxConstList. But I'm wondering what is the meaning of `surround a variable with parenthesis only`?

That is:

```c
List_t * const pxConstList = ( pxList );
                             ~~~~~~~~~~
```

and

```c
( pxTCB ) = ( pxConstList )->pxIndex->pvOwner;
~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

These variables are actually parameters to a macro.  The parenthesis are necessary because a parameter may be an expression that wouldn't fit properly in context without them.

Consider for example this macro:

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
```

If you called this macro like this:

```
SQUARE(4+5)
```

You would get:

```
4+5*4+5
```

Because `*` has higher precedence than `+`, this would evaluate to 29 instead of the expected 81.  If the macro were defined like this:

```
#define SQUARE(x) (x)*(x)
```

Then the above would expand to:

```
(4+5)*(4+5)
```

Which would evaluate to 81.

So to summarize, it's recommended to **always** parenthesize macro parameters to avoid these types of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `listGET_OWNER_OF_NEXT_ENTRY` is a macro (not a function), i.e. `pxTCB` and  `pxList` will be copy-pasted. if they are expressions you have to put parenthesis around them. why? see here [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)