# Can someone please explain why the output of this code is 3 and not 4?

Tags: c++, c

Can someone please explain why the output of this code is 3 and not 4?

```
#define square(x) (x*x)

int main () {
    int x,y=1;
    x=square(y+1);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: what is `1+1*1+1` ?

Comment: Hi @Catastrophe, Could you make your code more clear?

Comment: the code is quite clear as is the problem....already answered above.

Comment: This is one reason using macros should be avoided in favor of functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Comment: x = (y+1*y+1);  using -save-temps with gcc...

Comment: To expand on the comment from @M.M, what is the result of `y+1*y+1`?

Comment: Try changing the macro to `#define square(x) ((x)*(x))`

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that what preprocessor does about macros is quite like a search-replace. So you get `y+1*y+1` which gives three. To avoid such problems

- wrap every variable in macro definition with parentheses `#define square(x) ((x)*(x))`
- use functions instead (prefered as less likely to run into random errors)