# Macro doesn't handle bool conditions when they are "inline" but works via variable

Tags: c++

I've written a basic macro which asserts regardless of debug or not:

```
#define ASSERT_ALWAYS(cond) \
    do                      \
    {                       \
        if (!cond)          \
        {                   \
            std::abort();   \
        }                   \
    } while(0)              \
```

The strange thing is it compiles if I use a variable:

```
const bool s = myObj.anEnum != AnEnum::C;
ASSERT_ALWAYS(s);
```

but without the variable this doesn't compile:

```
ASSERT_ALWAYS(myObj.anEnum != AnEnum::C);
```

I get this compiler error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator!’ (operand type is ‘AnEnum::C’)
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘AnEnum::C’ to ‘bool’
```

AnEnum is declared like this:

```
enum class AnEnum : char {
  A = '0',
  B = '2',
  C
};
```

I get similar compiler errors for other types I try to change, so is the problem with my macro?

Comment: `if (!(cond))` may help. Note the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Is `MY_ASSERT` the same thing as `ASSERT_ALWAYS`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Comment: You can get the same behavior with a function, instead of a macro. Why not go for the simpler solution (the function)?

Comment: Macros work by text substitution. So `ASSERT_ALWAYS(myObj.anEnum != AnEnum::C);` expands to `... if(!myObj.anEnum != AnEnum::C) ... `, which in turn is trying to check whether `!myObj.anEnum` is not equal to `AnEnum::C`. The suggested parentheses around `(cond)` will impose the correct precedence. But you could also just make this a function that accepts a `bool` instead of using a macro at all.

Comment: Why not just use `assert`? It gives a nicer error when it aborts too.

Answer (score 5):

When you use the expression, the preprocessor pastes

```cpp
if(!myObj.anEnum != AnEnum::C)
```

so the compiler processes

```cpp
if( (!myObj.anEnum) != (AnEnum::C) )
```

and the error makes more sense.

What you need is `if(!(cond))`.

Comment: @bcguy Most ide's will tell you what an (macro) expression is being expanded to, when you hover it.

Comment: @bcguy -- that's one of the drawbacks with macros: they don't behave the way you expect them to. The rule of thumb is to always put parentheses around uses of the macro arguments and, if the macro is just a computation, put parentheses around the whole thing. `#define my_expr(x) ((x)*3)`.