# Are parentheses needed when a define sets something to an integer?

Tags: c, macros, embedded, c-preprocessor

In C, it's known that `#define` macros should make use of parentheses.  See e.g. [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses).

However, in embedded code, I frequently see this used even with *integers*.  E.g.:

```
#define OFFSET (0x100)
```

What is the point of the parens when the macro is simply a constant integer? What case could they make a difference?

Comment: You have to ask the developers using that style why they use it. Because it's not strictly needed.

Comment: Not needed. It would make a difference in some contexts such as `inttakingfunction OFFSET` either being a syntactic error or it being a valid function call, but the latter here would usually be undesirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless they are used in specific constructions, macros should expand to a single primary expression or a single statement without the trailing semicolon.  The reason for this is to prevent operator precedence issues when the macro is invoked as part of an expression or as a statement in a compound statement.

Surrounding the expansion with a set of parentheses is a simple way to ensure the expansion is a primary expression.  Yet as you noticed, numeric constants and string literals do not require the set of parentheses for this purpose.

Note however that the parentheses are recommended for negative numbers, which are expressions, not numeric constants, as in

```
#define EOF  (-1)
```

So using parentheses for both positive and negatives numbers can be a matter of consistency.

The example posted seems to be a case of one or a combination of these:

- unnecessarily strict coding rules: *always use parentheses*
- overcautious programmer: *when in doubt, use parentheses*
- consistency and clarity for the next reader, albeit in your case it prompted more questions

The extra parentheses make no difference in most cases.  They will however have some side effects in extreme cases that are errors or horrors anyway:

- `func OFFSET` will compile to a function call of `func` with a single argument `0x100`
- the parentheses will prevent token pasting (to be avoided anyway):

```
#define MAKE_LONG(n)  n##L
long var1 = MAKE_LONG(100);      // expands to 100L, a long constant
long var2 = MAKE_LONG(OFFSET);   // expands to (0x100)L, an invalid token error
```

More importantly, macro arguments should always be surrounded with a set of parentheses except possibly when used as function or macro arguments in the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of the parens when the macro is simply a constant integer?

I think it is for clarity, it makes the code more explicit and easier to understand for other developers when it is Include parentheses.

moreover, it also depends on the coding style  of the developer that familiar with.

it's a good to use parentheses in macros, even when defining constant integer values.

this practice can help you prevent subtle issues and/or make your code more maintainable/readable

The subtle issues is such as:

- Avoid Unexpected Side Effects
- Operator Precedence
- Type Safety
- ...

> What case could they make a difference?

in my experience, it's maybe NO.