# syntax of macro-like function in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In the web, I read that to define a macro that behave like a function, the syntax is:

```c
#define foo(x,y) (bar((x),(y)))
```

but considering that a macro is just text replacement, why is the syntax above used, and not just `(bar(x,y))` or `bar(x,y)`?

If I write

```c
#define add0(x,y) ((x)+(y))

#define add1(x,y) (x+y)

#define add2(x,y) x+y
```

All of the three macros output `3` when printed.

Comment: Maybe think about a tiny change: `#define mydiv(a,b) (a/b)` and then use `mydiv(1, 0+2)`

Comment: Macro processing does not use text replacement. It uses preprocessor token replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

> [C macros and use of arguments in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186504/c-macros-and-use-of-arguments-in-parentheses)

Writing without parentheses can lead to unexpected operator precedence problems.

Consider the following example:

```
#define add2(x,y) x+y
```

If you call add2(1, 2) * 3, it would expand to 1 + 2 * 3, which is 7, not 9. This is because the multiplication operator has higher precedence than the addition operator in C and C++.

However, if you define the macro as:

```
#define add0(x,y) ((x)+(y))
```

It's fine now.